# Mounting a mosaic modularly

Tags: building, disassembly, mosaic

I have this LEGO mosaic consisting out of 3 by 3 baseplates (32x32):
[image: mosaic]

As it takes up too much space lying flat, I would like to mount it vertically or near vertically, slightly leaning backwards, like on an easel.

I'm looking for a solution that is modular, i.e. that I can easily take apart in smaller parts so I can put it in luggage for travelling and that is also as easy as possible to reassemble.

Also, I'd prefer a purist lego only solution, avoiding gluing if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest using a base [MILS](http://www.abellon.net/MILS/) module (BTM-1 on the picture below), basically an extra layer including some Technic Bricks around the edge for connectivity between modules as well as some plates on top of existing baseplate. Yes, it is going to be bulkier and heavier, but at the same time much more sturdy and easy to assemble and take apart for travelling.

This also has an added benefit of making your surface 3D (BTM-2) if needed.

[image]

**UPDATE**

LEGO has now produced their own MILS-like elements used as a base layer for mosaic sets as well - [Technic, Brick 16 x 16 x 1 1/3 with Holes (65803)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=65803&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

[image]

Comment: Fits the modular requirement for sure, however I think mounting MILS modules vertically might be a tad problematic.

Comment: Are you looking to hang mosaic on the wall or use some sort of stand for vertical orientation? MILS modules have Technic bricks on the edge. This is a great advantage and can be utilised to further strengthen the structure. Attaching extra Technic beam/liftarm/brick on side to make sure both modules won't disconnect. Going even further frame can be built around MILS modules for hanging or free-standing with the help of other Technic bits.